# mysql mostrar registros por hora

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Saludos necesito agrupar registros por hora en un rango (de 7 a 16) en mysql pero también necesito que aparezcan las horas donde no hay registro osea si hubo a las 7, 8, 9 pero a las 10 no hay registros necesito que salga la hora y tal vez un cero si hay resultados nulos

Por ejemplo tengo esta consulta

```
select HOUR(created_at) as hora, asunto as name, COUNT(turno) as numero from tikets 
where estado = 1 and id_sucursal = 1 
and asunto = 'Factibilidad' 
and DATE(created_at) = '2017-06-14'
GROUP BY hora ASC
```

que me arroja esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ocupo que me arroje algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como podría plantearlo si necesito otra table o como podría hacer el select se los agradecería

Comment: Creo que está mal planteada tu pregunta o me confunde el saber que es lo que quieres. Si deseas agrupar o deseas que aparezca un cero si es null o las dos cosas.

Answer (score 1):

Para ello lo que necesitas es usar ISNULL(columna, 'valor en caso de ser null'), donde tu sentencia seria:

```
ISNULL(columna, 0)
```

Si pudieras editar tu pregunta con las tablas y unos datos podria darte la sentencia específica, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT HORA,IFNULL(NUM_TURNOS,0) FROM MITABLA;
```

Creo que deberías actualizar tu pregunta, o decir que es lo que te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

**Group by** no te mostrará nunca las horas en las que no tienes registros.

Puedes crear una tabla "**Virtual**" con las horas que quieres mostrar, después hacer un **left join** entre esta y la tabla que has mostrado en el ejemplo.

**Ejemplo de tabla virtual**

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT 7 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 8 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 9 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 10 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 11 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 12 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 13 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 14 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 15 AS hora UNION
    SELECT 16 AS hora
) listadehoras
```